# how to show the proper number of columns in a QTreeView for a model with different hierarchical column counts

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

In the code example below I populate an item model with a set of top level items which contain key-value properties that I can view and edit with a QTreeView.

Looking at the Qt Documentation for [QAbstractItemModel::columnCount](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#hasChildren) it says that this should return the number of columns for the children of the given parent, meaning that this should be a hierarchical dependent property.

However, using the code below, if I return the column count as a hierarchical dependent property (in this case `root->children` have 1 column, `root->child->children` have 2 columns) then the view will only display 1 column.

[image]

Printing `node.columnCount()` (see the code) will actually show that the `Item` class nodes do in fact return columnCount = 2 after you expand one of the items.

If I just always return 2 for the `model.columnCount` function, then the view will properly display both columns.

[image]

Is this required to always return the desired number of columns in a view no matter the hierarchy or am I just doing something wrong and if so what?  Returning a number of columns for a parent whose children have a different number of columns just to make the view work properly feels like it must be wrong.

```
import sys
import typing
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Node:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent  # type: Node
        self.name : str

    def children(self) -> list:
        return None

    def hasChildren(self):
        return bool(self.children())

    def getData(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        if index.column() == 0:
            return self.name

    def setData(self, val, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        if index.column() == 0:
            self.name = val

    def columnCount(self):
        return 1

    def rowCount(self):
        children = self.children()
        return 0 if not children else len(children)

    def flags(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        if index.column() == 0:
            return (QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        else:
            return QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags


class Property(Node):
    def __init__(self, parent, label, value):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = label
        self.value = value

    def getData(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        col = index.column()
        if col == 0:
            return self.label
        elif col == 1:
            return self.value

    def setData(self, val, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        if index.column() == 1:
            self.value = val

    def flags(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        col = index.column()
        if col == 0:
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        elif col == 1:
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable


class Item(Node):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.name = 'Item'
        self.p1 = Property(self, 'string', 'text')
        self.p2 = Property(self, 'float', 1.2)

    def children(self):
        return [self.p1, self.p2]

    def columnCount(self):
        return 2


class Root(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self._children = list()

    def children(self):
        return self._children


class Model(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.root = Root()

    def index(self, row: int, column: int, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> QtCore.QModelIndex:
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        node = parent.internalPointer() if parent.isValid() else self.root
        if node.children:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, node.children()[row])
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, child: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> QtCore.QModelIndex:
        if not child.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        node = child.internalPointer()  # type: Node

        if node.parent and node.parent.parent:
            row = node.parent.parent.children().index(node.parent)
            return self.createIndex(row, 0, node.parent)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        node = parent.internalPointer() if parent.isValid() else self.root
        children = node.children()
        return len(children) if children else 0

    def columnCount(self, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        node = parent.internalPointer() if parent.isValid() else self.root
        print(f'{node.__class__.__name__} column count: ', node.columnCount())  # shows that column count 2 is returned, when items are expanded
        # return 2  # 2nd column only shows up if I just always return 2
        return node.columnCount()  # view only shows 1 columns

    def hasChildren(self, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> bool:
        node = parent.internalPointer() if parent.isValid() else self.root
        return node.hasChildren()

    def data(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex, role: int = ...):
        if index.isValid() and role in (QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
            node = index.internalPointer()  # type: Node
            return node.getData(index)
        else:
            return None

    def setData(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex, value: typing.Any, role: int = ...) -> bool:
        if role in (QtCore.Qt.EditRole,):
            node = index.internalPointer()  # type: Node
            node.setData(value, index)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def flags(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        node = index.internalPointer() if index.isValid() else self.root
        return node.flags(index)

    def appendRow(self, item):
        row = len(self.root.children())
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row)
        self.root.children().append(item)
        self.endInsertRows()


class TreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TreeView, self).__init__(parent)
        self._model = Model()
        self.setModel(self._model)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ExtendedSelection)
        # self.setDropIndicatorShown(False)
        self.setEditTriggers(self.DoubleClicked | self.SelectedClicked | self.EditKeyPressed)

    def model(self) -> Model:
        return self._model

sys.excepthook = sys.__excepthook__
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = TreeView()
model = widget.model()
for i in range(2):
    model.appendRow(Item(model.root))
widget.show()
widget.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the docs is not clear and does not exactly match the implementation, in the implementation the number of columns in the view is dependent on the *horizontal `QHeaderView`*, and the *horizontal `QHeaderView`* uses the number of columns of the root that is the invisible item, ie the number of columns should be given by `Root()`, and since `Root()` does not overwrite the `columnCount()` it will have the value of 1 by default (although for me the `columnCount()` of Node must be 0 and `children()` must return a empty list), so the solution is set to 2 in Root `columnCount()`.

```
import sys
import typing
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Node:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent  # type: Node
        self.name : str

    def children(self) -> list:
        return list()

    def hasChildren(self):
        return bool(self.children())

    def getData(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        if index.column() == 0:
            return self.name

    def setData(self, val, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        if index.column() == 0:
            self.name = val

    def columnCount(self):
        return 0

    def rowCount(self):
        children = self.children()
        return len(children)

    def flags(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        if index.column() == 0:
            return (QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        else:
            return QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags


class Property(Node):
    def __init__(self, parent, label, value):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = label
        self.value = value

    def getData(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        col = index.column()
        if col == 0:
            return self.label
        elif col == 1:
            return self.value

    def setData(self, val, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        if index.column() == 1:
            self.value = val

    def flags(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        col = index.column()
        if col == 0:
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        elif col == 1:
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def columnCount(self):
        return 1


class Item(Node):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.name = 'Item'
        self.p1 = Property(self, 'string', 'text')
        self.p2 = Property(self, 'float', 1.2)

    def children(self):
        return [self.p1, self.p2]

    def columnCount(self):
        return 2


class Root(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self._children = list()

    def children(self):
        return self._children

    def columnCount(self):
        return 2


class Model(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.root = Root()

    def index(self, row: int, column: int, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> QtCore.QModelIndex:
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        node = parent.internalPointer() if parent.isValid() else self.root
        if node.children:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, node.children()[row])
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, child: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> QtCore.QModelIndex:
        if not child.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        node = child.internalPointer()  # type: Node

        if node.parent and node.parent.parent:
            row = node.parent.parent.children().index(node.parent)
            return self.createIndex(row, 0, node.parent)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        node = parent.internalPointer() if parent.isValid() else self.root
        children = node.children()
        return len(children) if children else 0

    def columnCount(self, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        node = parent.internalPointer() if parent.isValid() else self.root
        print(f'{node.__class__.__name__} column count: ', node.columnCount())  # shows that column count 2 is returned, when items are expanded
        # return 2  # 2nd column only shows up if I just always return 2
        return node.columnCount()  # view only shows 1 columns

    def hasChildren(self, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> bool:
        node = parent.internalPointer() if parent.isValid() else self.root
        return node.hasChildren()

    def data(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex, role: int = ...):
        if index.isValid() and role in (QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
            node = index.internalPointer()  # type: Node
            return node.getData(index)
        else:
            return None

    def setData(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex, value: typing.Any, role: int = ...) -> bool:
        if role in (QtCore.Qt.EditRole,):
            node = index.internalPointer()  # type: Node
            node.setData(value, index)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def flags(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        node = index.internalPointer() if index.isValid() else self.root
        return node.flags(index)

    def appendRow(self, item):
        row = len(self.root.children())
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row)
        self.root.children().append(item)
        self.endInsertRows()


class TreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TreeView, self).__init__(parent)
        self._model = Model()
        self.setModel(self._model)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ExtendedSelection)
        # self.setDropIndicatorShown(False)
        self.setEditTriggers(self.DoubleClicked | self.SelectedClicked | self.EditKeyPressed)

    def model(self) -> Model:
        return self._model

sys.excepthook = sys.__excepthook__
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = TreeView()
model = widget.model()
for i in range(2):
    model.appendRow(Item(model.root))
widget.show()
widget.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The notion that root should return column count of 2 seems wrong since the children of root have only 1 column. But perhaps you are right that the view only looks at the column count of root. Is that the case? Is that stated somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: @VinceW. It seems but that is what is indicated in the implementation: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qheaderview.cpp#n1942

Comment: @VinceW. In the previous link, point out how the columnCount calculates the QHeaderView: *if (parent != d->root)
        return; // we only handle changes in the root level*, and in this link I show you that the number of QTreeView columns depends on the QHeaderView http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qtreeview.cpp#n326

Comment: @VinceW. If QStandardItemModel is checked, the number of columns is set by invisibleRootItem(): http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/itemmodels/qstandarditemmodel.cpp#n2334

Comment: Really appreciate the digging. I get what you’re saying but I’m trying to dig through the code on my phone but I need to check it out on my computer. Will give it a deep look through in the morning.

Comment: @VinceW. I think that implementation is given because the QHeaderView is used must match the number of columns in the view, and if the number of columns is variable the calculation would be heavy.

Comment: Thanks for the links in the source code.  I wonder what is the point of calling columnCount?

Answer (score 1):

As @eyllanesc answered, the number of columns in the View is only affected by the root item.  However, `columnCount()` will have an effect on rows that give a number that is less than this number, in that columns less than this number will not be populated.

Taking the above code:

```
class Root(Node):
    ...
    def columnCount():
        return 2

class Property(Node):
    ...
    def columnCount():
        return 1
```

In this case even though two columns are shown, the `Property` nodes will not show data for the second column because the view is being told by `columnCount()` that there is only 1 column